# Starting with a smaller child width, is it possible to set it equal to its parent width by shrinking the browser window using only relative widths?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a parent element with a relative width. With the browser fully expanded, its child element has a smaller width. By shrinking the browser, I can make the child element retain its width until it eventually becomes the SAME width as its parent element and subsequent shrinking causes both elements to retain equal width, but I have to use a FIXED max-width and can't make it work for a relative max-width. For example, I want to be able to achieve this by giving the child element `max-width: 50%` rather than `max-width: 900px`. [Here is the CodePen.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZpZAxd)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
<div id="firstDiv"</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
width:90%; 
margin: 0 auto;
height: 300px;
background-color: #2b6dad;
border: 8px solid #2b6dad;
}

#firstDiv {
max-width: 800px;      /*works for FIXED width*/
/*max-width: 50%;/*    /*Doesn't work for RELATIVE width*/
height: 100%; 
background-color: #da2225; 
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, when it's loaded it's 50% of parent but as soon as you start shrink browser window, it keeps its width until it matches its parent, and then ... resizes with parent or keeps its size and gets hidden inside parent?

Comment: Exactly, it keeps its width until it matches with the parent and then resizes with said parent. I know I can do this through media queries, which I do use, I just want to know if there's a better way to do this specifically.

Comment: Now you got an answer by Yuri that works very well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container {
  width:90%; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #2b6dad;
  border: 8px solid #2b6dad;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#firstDiv {
  min-width: 50%;      
  width: 300px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: #da2225; 
  margin: auto;
  border-left: solid black 5px;
  border-right: solid black 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="firstDiv"</div>
</div>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/bwqvGO)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
#firstDiv {
  width: 50%;    /*Doesn't work for RELATIVE width*/
  height: 100%; 
  background-color: #da2225; 
  margin: auto;
 }
```

it may help you

Comment: I need the child width to eventually become equal to the parent width (demonstrated in the CodePen when you shrink the browser), so unfortunately this doesn't work for me.

Comment: then @media query would help you

Comment: I know, I just wanted to know if there was a better way to do it.

Comment: i think better way to use media query